# Issue with python loc on dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working on a project on python with jupyter notebook. I would like to predict stadium attendance in france (ligue 1).

To achieve that I have taken data from web with beautiful soup. I'm trying now to clean up my data : I have some missing values for the stadiums and I would like to assign stadium for a specific team (Olympique lyonnais).

I first tried that :

```
stats_match.stade[(stats_match.saison >= 2017) & (stats_match.domicile == 'Olympique Lyonnais') & (stats_match.stade.isna())] = 'Groupama stadium'
```

which gave me that error :

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

So I followed the instruction and tried that :

```
stats_match.stade.loc((stats_match.saison >= 2017) & (stats_match.domicile == 'Olympique Lyonnais') & (stats_match.stade.isna())) = 'Groupama stadium'
```

which give me :

> File "", line 3
>       stats_match.stade = stats_match.stade.loc((stats_match.saison >= 2017) & (stats_match.domicile == 'Olympique Lyonnais') & (stats_match.domicile.isna())) = 'Groupama stadium'
>   SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

What do I miss here ? Do I have to use .where function ?
Many thanks

Comment: The first issue is that `.loc` uses square brackets, not `.loc()`

Comment: Second, I don't think you want to be calling this on the series, but rather on the df itself

Comment: I do, because If I call it on the dataframe It would assign my value on all the columns, no ?

Comment: No, because `loc` allows you to specify the column that you want to transform, separated from your conditions by a comma but still inside the square brackets

Comment: It works thanks ! didn't know I could specify the colunm in the loc function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be correct;

```
stats_match.loc[(stats_match.saison >= 2017) & (stats_match.domicile == 'Olympique Lyonnais') & (stats_match.stade.isna())] = 'Groupama stadium'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay like @roganjosh said I put () instead of [], but I have now the same warning "SettingWithCopyWarning, I already had this warning and used .copy(), but is there a better way of doing it ?